# No visible interface for AppDelegate declares the selector

Tags: ios, class-method, appdelegate

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

+ (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title;
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
+ (MBProgressHUD *)showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject];
[MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:window animated:YES];
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
hud.labelText = title;
return hud;
}
```

In someOtherMethod in AppDelegate.m:

```
[self showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Checking for Updates"];  //No visible interface for AppDelegate declares the selector 'showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:'
```

Why? Other methods in the interface are visible, but why isn't this one? Does it have to do with being a Class method?

Comment: + is a class method, - is an instance method.  You don't execute that method on self, you execute it on AppDelegate.  You likely want to change the definition to -.

Comment: @StefanH that makes sense, but why can't I do this either (from a different class): AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; [appDelegate showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"whatever"];

Comment: Because `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` returns an instance of `AppDelegate`, not the class itself. To call the class method you need to do `[AppDelegate classMethodName]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a class method from an object instance (self).

Change + to - in your method declaration and implementation, and you're sorted.